# Mocking libraries in Jest

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, expo

I have some tests that keep failing..

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ignoreLogs')

      33 | // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state
      34 |
    > 35 | LogBox.ignoreLogs([
         |        ^
      36 |   'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
      37 | ]);
      38 |
```

I'm not entirely sure why.  I have tried mocking Logbox in my config file, and in the test individually.  Can anyone shed some light on why it is failing.  Wasn't a problem with jest 26.x, but after upgrading react-native to 0.70 and jest to 29/expo-jest to 49, I have been having problems. My mock is as such

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox', () => ({
  ignoreLogs: jest.fn(),
  ignoreAllLogs: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I too started seeing this error after upgrading to Expo 49 and jest-expo 49. Only a slight change is needed for your mock. If you look at the `react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox` file, you'll see that it exports a default export, whereas your mock has the module exporting two named exports. The following works for me:

```js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    ignoreLogs: jest.fn(),
    ignoreAllLogs: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
```